# Pandas loc works only with object type

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that represents data from an accelerometer that I have gathered. I am trying to combine 2 separate dataframes into one file, one of them has the accelerometer data. Im trying to find x,y,z values for a particular timestamp in this dataframe. I have tried to use `df.loc` but it only works with columns that have the object data type, in my case 'date' (I didn't bother changing it to datetime because I don't need to use it).

```
time      timedelta64[ns]
date               object
x_axis            float64
y_axis            float64
z_axis            float64
dtype: object
```

Im using this code to find the row by time:

```
test_df = dataset.set_index('time')
print(test_df.dtypes)
test_df.loc[18:40:01]
```

Here's my accelerometer data frame

```
time    date    x_axis  y_axis  z_axis
1.0 18:40:01    15/7/2018   0.776363    -1.106174   -7.898244
2.0 18:40:02    15/7/2018   1.503269    0.368612    -4.248112
3.0 18:40:03    15/7/2018   1.018665    2.070288    -3.869580
```

But it returns the error

```
KeyError: 'the label [0 days 18:40:01] is not in the [index]'
```

Same thing happens if I try to find a row by using some value from the x_axis column in `loc`

**EDIT** result of `print(test_df.index)` added below

```
Index(['18:40:1', '18:40:2', '18:40:3', '18:40:4', '18:40:5', '18:40:6',
       '18:40:7', '18:40:8', '18:40:9', '18:40:10',
       ...
       '17:20:40', '17:20:41', '17:20:42', '17:20:43', '17:20:44', '17:20:45',
       '17:20:46', '17:20:47', '17:20:48', '17:20:49'],
      dtype='object', name='time', length=80225)
```

Comment: For me it working nice, what return `print (test_df.index)` ?

Comment: @jezrael added the result in the edit above. Index looks fine, but it still isn't working :(

Comment: So if use `test_df.loc['18:40:01']` it failed?

Comment: Yup it says KeyError: 'the label [18:40:01] is not in the [index]'

Comment: hmm, index is changed for some reason, need `df = test_df.loc['18:40:1']`, so not possible select by `df = test_df.loc['18:40:01']` (check last `0`)

Comment: Maybe help if convert index to timedeltaindex by `test_df.index = pd.to_timedelta(test_df.index)`, then working `test_df.loc['18:40:01']`

Comment: Thanks bro this did the trick, for some reason maybe pandas was converting the timedelta to some other data type in the index :)

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: pandas version 0.22.0

Comment: It is not old. So what is `print(dataset['time'].dtypes)` before `set_index`  ?

Comment: It is object, as can also be seen in the index print in the question. It's my mistake i did not convert the 'time' column to timedelta after importing the csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is problem need convert index to `TimedeltaIndex`:

```
test_df.index = pd.to_timedelta(test_df.index)
```

Or change selecting strings by remove last `0`:

```
df = test_df.loc['18:40:1']
```